# Searching outlook folder BY attachment filename

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am currently using Outlook 2010 and I am currently able to manually search a folder in outlook by using the "More" button and adding attachments:yes and attachment contains: where I input the filename to find an email and get the timestamp from when it was sent. I have thousands of attachments for which I need to do this and I would like to automate the process but I am an outlook vba noobie and I do not know the command to perform the search by attachment name, I have tried googling this but to no avail any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: yes because I am asking for the particular code that would allow me to search an entire outlook folder by Attachment name so I can get the timestamp for that email, which then my existing code will update a database with these values based on filenames and there are thousands of line items. I have the rest of the process automated already I just need these timestamps by attachment name in outlook

Answer (score 0):

You can use Restrict https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx

Example here: http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/save-all-attachments-from-selected-folder/

```
Set newItems = itms.Restrict("[Attachment] > 0")
```

Combined with:

```
attName = MsgAttach.Item(attachmentNumber)

If InStr(attName, "search string here") Then
    Debug.Print "- " & attName
End If
```

Comment: This will return items that have attachments, but you will not be able to search by an attachment file name

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model will not let you search for an item with a particular attachment file name. You can explicitly loop through all items in the folder and check the attachment filename, but that will be highly inefficient.

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi) you can create a subrestriction on the attachments. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am its author), it allows to specify Attachments in [RDOItems](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm).`Find`/`Restrict`:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set vFolder = Session.GetFolderFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.EntryID)
set vItems = vFolder.Items
set vMsg = vItems.Find("Attachments LIKE '%.zip%' ")
while not (vMsg Is Nothing)
  MsgBox vMsg.Subject
  set vMsg = vItems.FindNext
wend
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I appreciate it. I think this is a step in th right direction for sure, how can I incorporate this into the code I have already written? for example putting this into an excel module. So far if I create a module in outlook and try to run it in a new sub I get an error on .mapiobject saying method or data member not found. I presume there are prerequesites for making this code functional.

Comment: Actually I just read one of your answering threads on the microsoft website and I changed session to rsession(and it works flawlessly thank you), as I am testing this in outlook right now before putting it in my excel macro. Will anything need be changed in the excel macro i.e should it be "session" or "rsession"?

Comment: Yes, in Excel it might be a good idea to change Session to rSession to avoid a conflict with the Excel VBA intrinsic variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, now that I can make this work in outlook the real part of the code will have to be in my excel code, I have tried both session and rsession in excel now neither will allow this code to work I still get the .mapiobject error (method or data member not found) what could be causing this? I have redemption outlook and MAPI COM Library enabled.

Comment: sorry the error on line "rSession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT" is object doesn't support property or method

Comment: The code above assume that Application intrinsic variable points to an instance of the Outlook.Application object. In case of Excel VBA it will point to an instance of the Excel.Application object

Comment: so in this case I assume I need to create an outlook object prior to using this code is this correct?

Comment: That is correct - CreateObject(Outlook.Application") will do.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have one final hurdle to overcome which is how can I redirect this .CurrentFolder to being a public folder with a name? I have tried using [link]http://www.outlookcode.com/d/code/getfolder.htm and trying Folders(getfolder("Folder Name Here")) instead of CurrentFolder but it does not work. I understand that this is outlook specific code, so it will need to be adapted. When attempting to use it in excel I tried using my variable "New_ol" which is the CreateObject("Outook.Application") but I cannot seem to use it in the function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487913/access-public-outlook-folders that is the link to the thread in which I am asking about this particular problem, thank you for the response. I am sure this is probably a very simple fix and I am thinking it likely has something to do with the function not being formatted for excel.